# Asp.net MVC change css on publish

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have an MVC application that is deployed as 3 different versions in production (seperate business areas demand seperate DBs and UIs).  The only problem is that a few users use more than 1 of these applications and because they look vsually similar people get confused as to which one they are using.

I use web.config transforms to change the app title but what  would like to do is deliver each one with a different css file.  Is there a way to:

Use transforms on publish to edit an existing css file?
or
Swap the css file for another on publish?

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be great.
Thanks

Comment: But the resulting HTML of the apps don't have different classes, IDs etc?

Comment: Yes Html of the two apps would be identical as far as possible to minimise maintenance.

Comment: Love to know whay I got the down vote ?

Comment: I'm just guessing but I'd think your downvotes are coming from people who think the design decision for having multiple versions of the same site is a bad idea. In case you consider the alternative of having a single site, take a look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks, nice to have a clue.  If they commented to that effect I would be happy to discuss design decisions with them but not all of us live in a world where "clean" solutions are available to them.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in a similar case : I dynamicly put a class on the body `<body class="theme-site@AppSettingParam">` and i have only one CSS with override like :

```
.theme-site1 { background-color:blue; }
.theme-site2 { background-color:red; }
```

if a user uses multiple sites, it does not re-download the css and i have only one css to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

This **isn't** the answer you're looking for right now, but if you do reconsider using the same site with different configurations, take a look at what I did recently to dynamically change CSS etc:

I decided that each 'version' of the website would use a unique reference in the query string. Based on this, I'll find the correct content, load the paths into a Model and send it to the view.

Here's the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<string> listOfAcceptableRef = new List<string>() { "uniqueCode1", "uniqueCode2" };
            string uniqueRef=null;
            if (Request.QueryString["ref"]!=null)
                policyRef = Request.QueryString["ref"].ToLower();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uniqueRef) || (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uniqueRef) && !listOfAcceptableRef.Contains(uniqueRef)))
            {
                throw new Exception("This reference key is unknown.");
                //return RedirectToAction("KeyError");
            }
            return View(GetPageContext(uniqueRef));
        }
```

Grab the reference code from the query string and then generate a model containing the relevant CSS paths from a context factory.

Here's my model:

```
public class PageContext
    {
        public string Ref { get; set; }
        public string TabId { get; set; }
        public string TabName { get; set; }
        public string SiteTitle { get; set; }
        public string CssPath { get; set; }

        public PageContext()
        {
            Products = new List<ProductInfo>();
        }
    }
```

And my context factory:

```
public class ContextFactory<T>
    {
        private ContextFactory()
        {

        }

        static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _dict = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
            {
                { "uniqueRef1", Type.GetType("The.Full.Page.Namespace.UniqueSite1Context")},
                { "uniqueRef2", Type.GetType("The.Full.Page.Namespace.UniqueSite2Context")}
            };

        public static bool Create(string reference, out T context)
        {
            context = default(T);
            Type type = null;
            if (_dict.TryGetValue(reference, out type))
            {
                context = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And the actual context instance with the CSS paths etc:

```
public class UniqueSite1Context : PageContext
    {
        public UniqueSite1Context()
        {
            this.Ref = "uniqueSite1";
            this.CssPath = "Content/UniqueSite1Context.css";
            this.DisclaimerPath = "Content/UniqueSite1Context.pdf";
            this.SiteTitle = "UniqueSite1";

        }
    }
```

After all that, just render the CSS using the model's paths:

```
@section Styles {
    @{
        string path = Url.Content("~") + Model.CssPath;

        <link href="@path" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    }
}
```

Architecturally speaking, you could extend this (or rather the **concept** of it) to use different logic and data contexts based on which 'site' the user goes to.

Comment: Like what you have done there but reusing the same site is not really an option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered transform files? They change the settings in your web.config file when you publish, based on the publish profile selected. Typically the profiles available by default is "Debug" and "Release", but you could add more like "Site1" and "Site2" with different CSS paths.

[Take a look at how they work here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) (I haven't used them myself so I can't help much in the way of code examples).

Comment: Yeah I already use transform files to change site name & database. I'm thinking that we use them in combination with Tonios answer.  So we get different settings in the config & display a different css file based on that.